# How to make a column with repeating rows only show one row at the top row SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query shown below, this query will pull the fruit and vegetable names and its categories.

The query is pulling the information, but I need to format properly for them to display like this:

If possible the more simpler the better, as I want to reproduce this query syntax for different purposes I have for other reports I will complete using this syntax given.

Also this is for SQL Server 2016.

What I have completed so far

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Food.Item_Name,
    Food.Category
FROM
    Food
```

Result:

| Item_Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Fruit |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Carrot | Vegetable |
| Potato | Vegetable |

The result I am looking for:

| Item_Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Fruit |
| Apple |  |
| Carrot | Vegetable |
| Potato |  |

Comment: also why would applle be empty and not banana?

Comment: There **IS NOT** SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 - take your pick

Comment: There is no such thing as a "top" of a table, a top or bottom, first or last, is dependent on how you are ordering you data - which you are not.

Comment: For the Apple Comment, I just used a exapmle of what I need it to look like. I am making a report with the same structure , but not about fruits and Vegatables. I just need to be able seperate or group by a specific value that repeats commonly through the Query.
You can picture also like this:
I have a order number 1234 and inside this order i have 5 items. I dont want the 5 items to show the 1234 5 times. i simply want it to display once from the first line item. and then for order 12345 i have 4 items, and I only want the order number to be shown once instead of all 4 times.

Comment: The top is just referencing the position I need it to be in.  You can simply say I need it to be positioned onto the first line item of the category types, instead of repeating individully for each and every single line item in this case. Just display at the beginning of every new set of category whether it be fruits, vegetables,  candies, snacks, desserts, ice creams etc.

Comment: @GerrellBones this sounds like a reporting problem rather than a sql query problem (apart from the lack of SORT). Which reporting tool are you using?

Comment: What you want to do runs in direct opposition to relational data principles. Not to say its impossible: just that it will be slow and awkward to do within the database, and you'll therefore likely be better off doing it in the client code or reporting tool.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a variety of ways, e.g.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID, Item_Name, Category,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category 
         ORDER BY Item_Name, ID) -- break ties deterministically
  FROM dbo.food
)
SELECT Item_Name, 
       DisplayCategory = CASE 
         WHEN rn = 1 THEN Category ELSE '' END
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY Category, rn;
```

(Also, you shouldn't need distinct unless you allow multiple foods with the same name in the same category, which would be bad.)

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sxtgtfI1)

However, I would argue that SQL Server isn't the place to do that. In the presentation layer, you have to loop through the rows and display them anyway. Shouldn't *that* be where you decide if the previous row is a repeat? Pseudo:

```
$lastCategory = "";

// get your recordset or data reader or whatever
// and start looping

IF rs("Category") <> $lastCategory
{
   SET $lastCategory = rs("Category")
   PRINT $lastCategory
}
ELSE
{
   PRINT '';
}
```

Comment: Oof, a combination of VBA syntax and C-style braces and semi-colons, along with PHP style variables and a mish-mash of quotes. I award you the Language Designer of the Year Award.

Comment: @Charlieface Just trying to cover all the bases.

Comment: @Charlieface, and i thought this was just a simple powershell

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Aaron about presentation layer.

This query does not use CTE's or window functions (ie row_number())

```
-- for simulation purposes - this will store sample data temporarily
declare @food table
(
    item_name varchar(255) not null,
    category varchar(255) not null
)

-- create some test data
insert into @food
select 'Artichokes', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Arugula', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Asparagus', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Avocados', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Basil', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Beets', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Black-eyed Peas', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Blood Oranges ', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Broccoli', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Carrots', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Cauliflower ', 'Fruit' union all
select 'Asparagus', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Broccoli', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Brussels Sprouts', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Cabbage ', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Celery', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Chayote Squash', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Collard Greens ', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Cucumbers', 'Vegetable' union all
select 'Endive', 'Vegetable'

-- we need to know what the start of a group is 
declare @food_min_name_by_group table
(
    item_name varchar(255) not null,
    category varchar(255) not null
)

insert into @food_min_name_by_group
select  min(f.item_name),
        f.category
from    @food f
group by    f.category


-- grab the data
select  fd.item_name,
        isnull(g.category, '') as category
from    @food fd
            left outer join 
        @food_min_name_by_group g on
                fd.item_name = g.item_name and
                fd.category = g.category
order by    fd.category, fd.item_name
```

[image]